# Masonry images design issue with MaterializeCSS "materialboxed" class

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I had created masonry images design with pure CSS.

[Link here to codepen (only html and css) No materialize CSS and JS](https://codepen.io/ferin-patel/pen/MWyZwBZ)

However, I want the effect of `materialboxed` class from materializeCSS

[Link to materialbox class from materializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/media.html)

**The problem is that when I add `materialboxed` class to image, the masonry layout is changed**

[link to codepen with masonary design + materializeCSS](https://codepen.io/ferin-patel/pen/WNwLvGZ)

[Expected Result](https://codepen.io/ferin-patel/pen/MWyZwBZ)

[Actual Result](https://codepen.io/ferin-patel/pen/WNwLvGZ)

#### Expected Result

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2vh;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.gallery .img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .img:first-child {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(4n + 5) {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(6n + 7) {
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}
.gallery .img:nth-child(8n + 9) {
  grid-column-start: span 1;
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}

.gallery .img img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.5) grayscale(100);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery .img:hover img {
  filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .gallery {
    display: block;
  }
  .gallery .img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    display: block;
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

#### Example with design not working with class materializedbox

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".materialboxed");
  M.Materialbox.init(elems);
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2vh;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.gallery .img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .img:first-child {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(4n + 5) {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(6n + 7) {
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}
.gallery .img:nth-child(8n + 9) {
  grid-column-start: span 1;
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}

.gallery .img img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.5) grayscale(100);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery .img:hover img {
  filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .gallery {
    display: block;
  }
  .gallery .img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    display: block;
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

    <section class="container">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please may you include a [mcve] in your question?
Let's say these links stop working, how can someone know what your question is?

Comment: @evolutionxbox   minimal reproducible example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add full width and height to `material-placeholder` to get it working.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".materialboxed");
  M.Materialbox.init(elems);
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2vh;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.gallery .img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery .img:first-child {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(4n + 5) {
  grid-column-start: span 2;
  grid-row-start: span 2;
}

.gallery .img:nth-child(6n + 7) {
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}
.gallery .img:nth-child(8n + 9) {
  grid-column-start: span 1;
  grid-row-start: span 1;
}

.gallery .img img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.5) grayscale(100);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.gallery .img:hover img {
  filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
}
.material-placeholder {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .gallery {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .gallery {
    display: block;
  }
  .gallery .img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .gallery .img img {
    display: block;
    filter: brightness(1) grayscale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

    <section class="container">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
          <img class="materialboxed" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```